# Dynamic partition cannot be the parent of a static partition

Tags: hive

I'm trying to aggregate data from 1 table (whose data is re-calculated monthly) in another table (holding the same data but for all time) in Hive. However, whenever I try to combine the data, I get the following error:

```
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10094]: Line 3:74 Dynamic partition cannot be the parent of a static partition 'category'
```

The code I'm using to create the tables is below:

```
create table my_data_by_category (views int, submissions int)
    partitioned by (category string)
    row format delimited
    fields terminated by ','
    escaped by '\\'
    location '${hiveconf:OUTPUT}/${hiveconf:DATE_DIR}/my_data_by_category';

create table if not exists my_data_lifetime_total_by_category
    like my_data_by_category
    row format delimited
    fields terminated by ','
    escaped by '\\'
    stored as textfile
    location '${hiveconf:OUTPUT}/lifetime-totals/my_data_by_category';
```

The code I'm using to populate the tables is below:

```
insert overwrite table my_data_by_category partition(category)
    select mdcc.col1, mdcc2.col2, pcc.category
    from my_data_col1_counts_by_category mdcc
    left outer join my_data_col2_counts_by_category mdcc2 where mdcc.category = mdcc2.category
    group by mdcc.category, mdcc.col1, mdcc2.col2;

insert overwrite table my_data_lifetime_total_by_category partition(category)
   select mdltc.col1 + mdc.col1 as col1, mdltc.col2 + mdc.col2, mdc.category
   from my_data_lifetime_total_by_category mdltc
   full outer join my_data_by_category mdc on mdltc.category = mdc.category
   where mdltc.col1 is not null and mdltc.col2 is not null;
```

The frustrating part is that I have this data partitioned on another column and repeating this same process with that partition works without a problem. I've tried Googling the "Dynamic partition cannot be the parent of a static partition" error message, but I can't find any guidance on what causes this or how it can be fixed. I'm pretty sure that there's an issue with a way that 1 or more of my tables is set up, but I can't see what. What's causing this error and what I can I do resolve it?

Comment: I know this is really old but I had this problem and there's not any information on this error. The problem, at least for me, was due to not having a column alias for a computed field. In the case above, `mdltc.col2 + mdc.col2` should be `mdltc.col2 + mdc.col2 as col2`. Nothing about the error would indicate that as the problem but that's absolutely what resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

There is no partitioned by clause in this script. As you are trying to insert into non partitioned table using partition in insert statement, it is failing.

```
create table if not exists my_data_lifetime_total_by_category
    like my_data_by_category
    row format delimited
    fields terminated by ','
    escaped by '\\'
    stored as textfile
    location '${hiveconf:OUTPUT}/lifetime-totals/my_data_by_category';
```

Comment: But if my_data_by_category is partitioned, shouldn't the like clause bring that partition to my_data_lifetime_total_by_category?

Comment: No, you need to define partition clause as part of DDL command.

Comment: Every attempt to add a "partitioned by" clause generates an error when I test the Hive script. Again, I have multiple other tables where this works without explicitly adding the partition, so I don't understand why it's an issue with this 1 table.

Comment: Can you share DDL command you are using to create the table and insert command?

Comment: The create table and insert overwrite table commands are in the original question, you can search for my_data_lifetime_total_by_category to see them.

Answer (score 0):

No. You don't need to add partition clause.

You are doing `group by mdcc.category` in `insert overwrite table my_data_by_category partition(category)....`. but you are not using any UDAF.
Are you sure you can do this?

Comment: category is a field in mdcc, so no UDAF is needed.

Comment: There is no mdcc.category column in your select clause by which you are trying to group by.

Comment: I mean there is a Typo. You are using 'mdcc.category' instead of 'pcc.category'. You can change either in GROUP BY or in SELECT clause.

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you change your second create statement to:

```
create table if not exists my_data_lifetime_total_by_category
partitioned by (category string)
row format delimited
fields terminated by ','
escaped by '\\'
stored as textfile
location '${hiveconf:OUTPUT}/lifetime-totals/my_data_by_category';
```

you should then be free of errors